# Use Source Reader to get H264 samples from webcam source

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

When using the [Source Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/source-reader) I can use it to get decoded YUV samples using an mp4 file source ([example code](https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/blob/master/MFMP4ToYUVWithoutMFT/MFMP4ToYUVWithoutMFT.cpp)).

How can I do the opposite with a webcam source? Use the Source Reader to provide encoded H264 samples? My webcam supports RGB24 and I420 pixel formats and I can get H264 samples if I manually wire up the H264 MFT transform. But it seems as is the Source Reader should be able to take care of the transform for me. I get an error whenever I attempt to set `MF_MT_SUBTYPE` of `MFVideoFormat_H264` on the Source Reader.

Sample snippet is shown below and the full example is [here](https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/blob/master/MFWebCamRtp/MFWebCamRtp.cpp).

```
  // Get the first available webcam.
  CHECK_HR(MFCreateAttributes(&videoConfig, 1), "Error creating video configuration.");

  // Request video capture devices.
  CHECK_HR(videoConfig->SetGUID(
    MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE,
    MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID), "Error initialising video configuration object.");

  CHECK_HR(videoConfig->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, WMMEDIASUBTYPE_I420),
    "Failed to set video sub type to I420.");

  CHECK_HR(MFEnumDeviceSources(videoConfig, &videoDevices, &videoDeviceCount), "Error enumerating video devices.");

  CHECK_HR(videoDevices[WEBCAM_DEVICE_INDEX]->GetAllocatedString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME, &webcamFriendlyName, &nameLength),
    "Error retrieving video device friendly name.\n");

  wprintf(L"First available webcam: %s\n", webcamFriendlyName);

  CHECK_HR(videoDevices[WEBCAM_DEVICE_INDEX]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pVideoSource)), 
    "Error activating video device.");

  CHECK_HR(MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 1),
    "Failed to create attributes.");

  // Adding this attribute creates a video source reader that will handle
  // colour conversion and avoid the need to manually convert between RGB24 and RGB32 etc.
  CHECK_HR(pAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_VIDEO_PROCESSING, 1),
    "Failed to set enable video processing attribute.");

  CHECK_HR(pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video), "Failed to set major video type.");

  // Create a source reader.
  CHECK_HR(MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(
    pVideoSource,
    pAttributes,
    &pVideoReader), "Error creating video source reader.");

  MFCreateMediaType(&pSrcOutMediaType);
  CHECK_HR(pSrcOutMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video), "Failed to set major video type.");
  CHECK_HR(pSrcOutMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264), "Error setting video sub type.");
  CHECK_HR(pSrcOutMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 240000), "Error setting average bit rate.");
  CHECK_HR(pSrcOutMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, 2), "Error setting interlace mode.");

  CHECK_HR(pVideoReader->SetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, NULL, pSrcOutMediaType),
    "Failed to set media type on source reader.");

  CHECK_HR(pVideoReader->GetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &pFirstOutputType),
    "Error retrieving current media type from first video stream.");

  std::cout << "Source reader output media type: " << GetMediaTypeDescription(pFirstOutputType) << std::endl << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
bind returned success
First available webcam: Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000
Failed to set media type on source reader. Error: C00D5212.
finished.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Source Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/source-reader) does not look like suitable API here. It is API to implement "half of pipeline" which includes necessary decoding but not encoding. The other half is [Sink Writer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/sink-writer) API which is capable to handle encoding, and which can encode H.264.

Or your another option, unless you are developing a UWP project, is [Media Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-session) API which implements a pipeline end to end.

Even though technically (in theory) you could have an encoding MFT as a part of Source Reader pipeline, Source Reader API itself is insufficiently flexible to add encoding style tansforms based on requested media types.

So, one solution could be to have Source Reader to read with necessary decoding (such as up to having RGB32 or NV12 video frames), then Sink Writer to manage encoding with respectively appropriate media sink on its end (or Sample Grabber as media sink). Another solution is to put Media Foundation primitives into Media Session pipeline which can manage both decoding and encoding parts, connected together.

Comment: And with a Media Session typically the Sample Grabber would be employed to access the IMFSample's? For the Sink Writer my understanding is there isn't an equivalent to the Source Reader? To access the raw samples a custom Sink Writer is required?

Comment: Source Reader is to read from "somewhere" and have bits of video and/or audio available to code. Sink Writer is the opposite: you have bits of data and you write to to get the data "somewhere else" with encoding if it is needed. Normally such result of Sink Writer is a file or streaming protocol, and if you want to regain access to produced data then you can set up Sink Writer with Sample Grabbers.

Comment: Just like with DirectShow I personally never use sample grabbers because custom filters are always a more flexible alternative. Same here in Media Foundation, custom sink is more flexible overall. Still Sample Grabber sink does work and is an easier way to consume output.

Comment: Got it thx. @mofo77 confused me a bit suggesting the Source Reader as a replacement for the Sample Grabber in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839187/sample-grabber-sink-not-setting-media-type-guid. But I understand now that makes sense for decoding scenarios only.

Answer (score 1):

Now, your use case is clearer.

For me, your MFWebCamRtp is the best optimized way of doing : WebCam Source Reader -> Encoding -> RTP Streaming.

But you are experiencing presentation clock issues, synchronization issues, or unsynchronized audio video issues. Am I right ?

So you tried Sample Grabber Sink, and now Source Reader, like I suggested to you. Of course, you can think that a Media Session will be able to do it better.
I think so, but extra work will be needed.

Here is what I would do in your case :

- Code a custom RTP Sink
- Create a topology with webcam source, h264 encoder, your custom RTP Sink
- Add your topology to a MediaSession
- Use the MediaSession to play the process

If you want a networkstream sink sample, see this : [MFSkJpegHttpStreamer](https://github.com/mofo7777/MFNode/tree/master/MFSkJpegHttpStreamer)

This is old, but it's a good start. This program also uses winsock, like your.

You should be aware that RTP protocol uses UDP. A very good way to have synchronization issues... Definitely your main problem, as I guess.

What I think. You are trying to compensate for the weaknesses of the RTP protocol (UDP), with a management of the audio / video synchronization of MediaFoundation. I think you will just fail with this approach.

I think your main problem is RTP protocol.

**EDIT**

> No I'm not having synchronisation issues. The Source Reader and Sample Grabber both provide correct timestamps which I can use in the RTP header. Likewise no problems with RTP/UDP etc. that's the bit I do know about. My questions are originating from a desire to understand the most efficient (least amount of plumbing code) and flexible solution. And yes it does look like a custom sink writer is the optimal solution.

Again things are clearer. If you need help with a custom RTP sink, I'll be there.

Comment: No I'm not having synchronisation issues. The Source Reader and Sample Grabber both provide correct timestamps which I can use in the RTP header. Likewise no problems with RTP/UDP etc. that's the bit I do know about. My questions are originating from a desire to understand the most efficient (least amount of plumbing code) and flexible solution. And yes it does look like a custom sink writer is the optimal solution.